# RegEx to Exclude series of 4 repeating characters but catch 2 repeating characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Trying to come up with a process in JavaScript to help convert custom date formats between different tech stacks so they all parse and display everything the same way.

I'm having trouble coming up with a good RegEx to convert,

`"dddd, dd/MM/yyyy"` to `"dddd, DD/MM/yyyy"`

and also,

`"ddd, dd/MM/yyyy"` to `"ddd, DD/MM/yyyy"`

I've tried negative lookahead and know I can do something like `(?!d{3,4})` to exclude the set of dddd and ddd.  I know I can also do `d{1,2}` to catch dd. But when I put them together, as `/(?!d{3,4})(d{1,2})/g` it also catches the last two dd inside dddd and gives me

`"ddDD, DD/MM/yyyy"`

I searched around for examples and was able to modify one to get this RegEx expression,

`/(?=\b|^)(?!d*([d])\1\1\w*)d+(?:\b|$)/g`

That does what I need but I don't really understand how it's working with catching the first group and such.  Is there a way I can simplify it for what I need or is there a simpler approach to this?

Comment: Looks like you need `/\bd{2}\b/g` - https://regex101.com/r/R0bBvJ/1

Comment: Don't use a regex? How is that a regex question at all - you either need a date library(-ies, depending on how many layers it goes through, though some will have in-built ones) or you do simple string manipulation to reorder the date parts or you don't do it that way at all. I'm pretty sure `dd` and `DD` are completely different. Also, just convert them to standard format like ISO 8601 and transfer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/(?=\b|^)(?!d*([d])\1\1\w*)d+(?:\b|$)/g` regex just matches `dd` as a whole word.

The `\b` (when followed with a word char ) also matches the start of string, so, no point in using `(?=\b|^)`, it is the same as `^`.

The `\w*` at the end of the negative lookahead is not necessary, it is redundant, as any other optional subpattern inside a negative lookahead.

Thus, you may use `/\bdd\b/g`.

Comment: That works perfect.  How does that solution exclude ddd?

Comment: The same way it is done in your pattern, I just reduced the groups with anchors and word boundaries to mere [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).